# i recently flashed ubuntu touch stable to my nexus 4 but the dialer app shows 'no network'

Tags: ubuntu-touch

i recently flashed ubuntu touch stable to my nexus 4 but the dialer app shows 'no network'and the message asks to select a sim eventhough a sim is inserted.
it needs mobile data turned on or wifi connected

Comment: After some reading on this issue, some people fixed this by flashing the latest version of android available for there nexus (lollipop probably ) and then re flashing Ubuntu, this seems to update the radio firmware, making there network connect. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2259691

Comment: After flashing to Lollipop you might run into boot issue I encountered. I had to flash Android 4.4.4 to be able to boot Ubuntu. Flashing Ubuntu over Lollipop ended in a broken Ubuntu. A catch 22? I don't have mobile network as well...

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, i just solved the issue. i erased ubuntu stable version from my phone and then flashed rc-proposed version of ubuntu touch and now everything is working fine as expected. The stable version must be updated in order to prevent problems.